# Get request params in Axios interceptor when the request is cancelled

Tags: javascript, axios

I have an interceptor:

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(doSomething, error => handleError(error));
```

I can access all the information about the request in `err.config` for "normal" errors

```js
const handleError = err => {
   if(err.config) {
      // use values from err.config
   }
}
```

However, `Cancel` error doesn't contain it. It only contains `message`.

Is it possible to access request parameters in the interceptor when the request has been cancelled?

Comment: You can accede to request parameters accessing to property `err.response`

Answer (score 0):

If you need something in particular when handling the `cancel` event - you need to provide that information at the place where you cancel the request:

```js
const token = CancelToken.source()
const request = axios.get('/url', { cancelToken: token }).then(....);
token.cancel(
... put here the information that will be available as the `err.message` parameter in the `cancel` interceptor
);
```